# JPA autoincrement non primary key column

Tags: jpa

How can i auto increment a non primary column using annotations.

I tried this but it is not working.

```
@Generated(value="GenerationTime.INSERT")
@GenericGenerator(name="id", strategy="sequence")
private Long id;
```

I am using mysql database

Answer (score 0):

`JPA` specification only provides for "id" fields to have their values generated. Any other fields are not supported. Some implementations (e.g `DataNucleus` `JPA`) support value generation on any field, but that is a vendor extension.

You could use prePersist callback and hook something in yourself if your provider doesn't support it

PS those annotations you use are NOT `JPA` annotations